# How to Change hover Color of Configurable drop Down menu in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

It is showing blue color by default and i need to change to different color..

Answer (score 1):

You can't override browser's select highlight color but you can implement you own UI and set it there.

You can try this one: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could change the background of `select` but you will not be able to change the highlight color (when you hover) by using CSS!

> You have few options:

1. Is to convert `select` into `ul, li` kind of select and do anything you want with this.
2. Use libraries like [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [jQuery Form Styler](https://github.com/Dimox/jQueryFormStyler) . These allow you to style in much more broad and cross-browser way.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown) question.